# Can't make Lua script in scrapy-splash get number of pages and click a button on a page

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash

### What I am trying to do

On https://www.contour.bg/myzhe I am trying to scrape all products and for that I need to click several times on next page button.
Hence I want to get from the page the number of pages and through the cycle to click on next page button as many times as needed.
I am using scrapy-splash through docker container.

### Problem

Currently my script looks like this, number of clicks is hardcoded and the button click doesn't work (the same page is scraped 10 times):

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  treat=require('treat')
  result= {}
  for i=1,10,1
  do
    assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".page-link.next").click()'))
    result[i]=splash:html()
  end
  return treat.as_array(result)
end
```

[On the image you can see the elements I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mmJ7.png)

### I've tried:

Replacing:

```
assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector(".page-link.next").click()'))
```

with

```
button = splash:select('.page-link.next') 
button:mouse_click()
```

but got the same result.

### I've also tried as suggested by [Darius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12918181/darius)

Adding waiting time and 'a' infront of '.page-link.next'.

```
assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("a.page-link.next").click()'))
assert(splash:wait(5))
result[i]=splash:html()
```

Like that when testing in docker container - the pages are actualy changing and content is showing up correctly, but when executing with scrapy I get an 504 error, which is probably due to website trying to stop scrapers.

Comment: You are clicking 10 times before page gets reloaded. After click you must  wait until new page is ready and then retrieve the content.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be part of the problem.
I added waiting time and 'a' infront of '.page-link.next'. 
```
assert(splash:runjs('document.querySelector("a.page-link.next").click()'))
assert(splash:wait(5))
result[i]=splash:html()
```
Like that when testing in docker container - the pages are changing and content is showing up correctly.